# Mapping dictionary

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping

I have 3 tables Users, AccessLevels, Roles. My User class have `public virtual Dictionary<Role,AccessLevel> Roles {get; set;}`, and 
Role class have `public virtual Dictionary<User,AccessLevel> Users {get;set;}` ? How such dictionaries should be represented in the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in FluentNhibernate it would look like

```
HasManyToMany(user => user.Roles)
    .Table("UserRoleAccessLevel")
    .AsEntityMap("role_id")
    .KeyColumn("user_id");

HasManyToMany(role => role.Users)
    .Table("UserRoleAccessLevel")
    .AsEntityMap("user_id")
    .KeyColumn("role_id");
```

can't test it right now though

Update: in hbm.xml

```
<map name="Roles" table="UserRoleAccessLevel">
  <key column="user_id" />
  <index-many-to-many class="Role" column="role_id" />
  <many-to-many class="AccessLevel" column="accesslevel_id" />
</map>

<map name="Users" table="UserRoleAccessLevel">
  <key column="role_id" />
  <index-many-to-many class="User" column="user_id" />
  <many-to-many class="AccessLevel" column="accesslevel_id" />
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am not familiar with FluentNHibernate. Can you say me how can i do this in mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

It would be very nice if you provided structure of your tables, especially AccessLevels table. As far as I could guess structure of your tables I can suggest you this mapping

```
<class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="Id" column="user_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="user_name" not-null="true" />

    <map name="Roles" table="AccessLevels" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <map-key-many-to-many column="role_id" class="Role" />
        <one-to-many class="AccessLevel"/>
    </map>
</class>

<class name="Role" table="Roles">
    <id name="Id" column="role_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="user_name" not-null="true" />
</class>

<class name="AccessLevel" table="AccessLevels">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Level" column="level" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="User" column="user_id" not-null="true" cascade="save-update" />
    <many-to-one name="Role" column="role_id"  not-null="true" cascade="save-update" />
</class>
```